# JS: Move a div outside his parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am testing this [table](http://ap.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/434-2/) and i wanted to know if is possible to move the

`<div id="tablepress-9_paginate">...</div>` outside the parent element.

**I am asking this because on mobile, when you scroll the table horizontally that div is fixed and is not visible anymore.**

Is possible to move it at the bottom of the table div?

PS: i am using **Wordpress**

Answer (score -2):

i think it will be easier with JQuery.remove().

pure js will be hard time to achieve this.

also sounds like you should just render the div outside the table and use CSS `position:fixed`

Comment: Could you explain me how to apply the jQuery script?

Comment: If i try position:fixed is automatically floated on left.

Comment: could you post an image of the expected result?